# How can I move a shape so its centre lines up with a cell left edge in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a group of shapes and I can currently move it to the top left edge of a reference cell however I need the middle of the shape to line up with this left edge. There is only "Top" and "Left" parameters and no "Middle" is there any way of doing this?

I could move to left edge then increment by x amount based on the column width but this seems long winded?

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim x
Set x = Range("A2")

Sheet1.Shapes("Group 9").Left = Sheet1.Cells(13, x).Left
Sheet1.Shapes("Group 9").Top = Sheet1.Cells(13, x).Top


End Sub
```

UPDATE:

My code is now as follows:

With Sheet1

```
    .Shapes("Group 9").Top = rng.Top
    .Shapes("Group 9").Left = rng.Left - (.Shapes("Group 9").Width / 2) + (rng.Width / 2)


End With
```

Which achieves the following

[image]

However I need to achieve this:

[image]

Whereby the inputed date in red means the shape centre aligns to the right edge of the cell in row 11 which matches the date in this case R11

Comment: Subtract half the Width/Height from the Left/Top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will center your shape on the range defined, modify as appropriate.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("D15")
With Sheet1
    .Shapes("Group 9").Left = rng.Left - (.Shapes("Group 9").Width / 2) + (rng.Width / 2)
    .Shapes("Group 9").Top = rng.Top - (.Shapes("Group 9").Height / 2) + (rng.Height / 2)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However this centres my shape to the centre of the range. I need the shape to centre on the left top edge of the range defined!

Comment: Delete everything on the rng.Left line after rng.Left

Comment: Thanks its getting closer...however please see my update!

Comment: Issue with my last screenshot please see now

Comment: Basically I have it perfectly lined up to the middle of the cell but I need the middle of the shape to the edge of the cell not the middle of shape to the middle of cell!

Comment: got it by commenting out '+ (rng.Width / 2)